# Formatting PDF docs w/ Coldfusion & DDX

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I've gotten a long way with manipulating PDFs in Coldfusion via DDX. The one thing I can't seem to find is actual document manipulation, such as size, etc.  I currently have 8.5x11 PDFs that I am appending Footers to.  However, most of the docs fill up the area.  I want to add 3" to put my Footer info.  Affectively making the docs 8.5x14 or Legal size.

This is where I am, so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DDX xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/DDX/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ns.adobe.com/DDX/1.0/ coldfusion_ddx.xsd">
<PDF result="Out1">
    <PDF source="Doc1" >
        <Footer>
            <Center>
                <StyledText>
                  <p>#name# - #divisionName# - #title#</p>
                  <p>#pa_category#</p>
                  <p>#pa_desc#</p>
                 </StyledText>
            </Center>
        </Footer>
    </PDF>
</PDF>
</DDX>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried ColdFusion Report Builder? Might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  At least not using DDX (unless you buy or have LifeCycle Assembler).  According to the Adobe's docs it says that "pageSize" is a excluded tag in Coldfusion.

You can use cfdocument to create a pdf and indicate the size.  You can find more here:

[CFDocument](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_05.html)

Hope this helps.